# INSERT INTO with RETURNING clause: return undefined columns?

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Breaking it down to it's most simplest form... Is it possible to use `INSERT INTO` with a `RETURNING` clause to capture a non-existing column alongside the output?

```
test=# \d x
       Table "public.x"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | integer | 
 b      | integer |
```

---

```
--void column does not exist in table...    
INSERT INTO x (a, void) values (1,2),(3,4) RETURNING a, void;
```

Under this scheme would return:

```
 a | void 
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
```

---

To give this problem some context...

I have a client ID that I'd like to append to the results so that it's server (real) ID will be returned alongside as a pair.

I don't actually need the client ID persisted to the DB.

I could use the `AS` keyword in the output, but there is no way to diversify the client ID with this method:

```
test=# INSERT INTO x (a, b) VALUES (1,2),(1,4) RETURNING a, b, 6 as clientid;
 a | b | clientid 
---+---+----------
 1 | 2 |        6
 1 | 4 |        6
(2 rows)

INSERT 0 2
```

I tried playing with some CTE's, can't seem to get it. Basically, I want to be able to provide a `ROW` or, array of IDs that I want `JOIN`ed to the result.

In theory, I could do this at the server level instead of DB level. Just curious.

Comment: You can use CTEs and then join the result of CTE a (the insert) with another CTE b (that provides a list of values).

Comment: It's not very clear though, who will provide these client values? Will/can they be part of the values that are inserted? Like this for example? `with v (a,b,clientid) as (values (1,2,6), (3,4,7)), i as (insert into x (a,b) select a,b from v returning a,b) select * from v ;` Or more complicated (with a join) so it can show additional columns from the inserted `i` table: `with v (a,b,clientid) as (values (1,2,6), (3,4,7)), i as (insert into x (a,b) select a,b from v returning *) select i.*,v.clientid from v join i using (a,b) ;`

Comment: @ypercube, awesome! your first solution works. Basically the client ID values will be provided at the server level that is producing the SQL string when building up the `VALUES( (...),(...) )`. Does it make sense? Please post your comment as an answer and I'm glad to accept.

Comment: I spoke too soon -- using your first solution, I was unable to return the server (real) id in the RETURNING clause, or any other column not present in the statements' column list. (I'm sure there is a way around this). So, I resorted to your second solution and I'm able to return both ids in the response. Excellence.

Comment: yes, if you want other columns from the inserted table (like a serial), the 2nd query works.